# MongoDB - Field not showing in Aggregate

Tags: mongodb

**Query:**

```
db.environments.aggregate(
[{$match:{customer:"CustomerName"}},
{$group:{_id:{environment: "$environment",
cpu_oversubscription:"$cpu_oversubscription",
memory_oversubscription:"$memory_oversubscription"}}} ])
```

When I run the query only the environment and the CPU_oversubcription fields are shown, the memory field is not shown.

This is the output I get:

```
[{"_id":{"environment":"V&B","cpu_oversubscription":1}}
```

When I run `db.environments.find()` I see all the fields

```
[{"_id":{"environment":"V&B","cpu_oversubscription":1,"memory_oversubscription":1,"customer":"CustomerName"}}
```

What is wrong with my query?

**Edit: Exact Query**

```
Environment.aggregate([{$match:{customer:req.query.customer}},{$group:{_id:{environment: "$environment",cpu_oversubscription:"$cpu_oversubscription",memory_oversubscription:"$memory_oversubscription",}}} ])
```

**Exact Result of Query**

```
{ "_id" : { "environment" : "1", "cpu_oversubscription" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : { "environment" : "2", "cpu_oversubscription" : 4 } }
{ "_id" : { "environment" : "3", "cpu_oversubscription" : 4 } }
{ "_id" : { "environment" : "4", "cpu_oversubscription" : 4 } }
{ "_id" : { "environment" : "5", "cpu_oversubscription" : 4 } }
{ "_id" : { "environment" : "6", "cpu_oversubscription" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : { "environment" : "7", "cpu_oversubscription" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : { "environment" : "8", "cpu_oversubscription" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : { "environment" : "9", "cpu_oversubscription" : 4 } }
{ "_id" : { "environment" : "10", "cpu_oversubscription" : 4 } }
```

**Exact result of db.environments.find()** (1st result only)

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("560a5139b56a71ea60890201"), "customer" : "CustomerName", "environment" : "1", "memory_oversubcription" : 1, "cpu_oversubscription" : 1 }
```

Comment: Is your data sample here correct? Everything is under `_id` and none of the fields in your aggregation ( seemingly based on questions asked and then answered by myself actually ) are prefixed with `_id` as in `{ "$group": { "_id": { "environment": "$_id.environment" } } }`. Mostly noting that this is not the structure posed in previous questions. So I think you have made a mistake in the post.

Comment: The query is correct but I don't see the point of it as you do not group anything in the end. If you don't use any of those operators : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator, a simple find can do the trick I think.

Comment: Why does cpu_oversubcription show, but memory_oversubscription does not?

Comment: Can you add a sample doc and tell us what is your requirement ?

Comment: @CMS it looks like you misplaced `memory_oversubcription` to  `memory_oversubscription`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Yogesh said, you have a typo in your field in your data. This solve your problem.

Nevertheless, you do not need the aggregation framework for this query : 
A *find* with a projection would be much more efficient :

```
db.environments.find({ "customer" : "CustomerName" }, 
                     { _id : 0, "environment" : 1,
                       "memory_oversubscription" : 1, 
                       "cpu_oversubscription" : 1
                     })
```

Result would be :

```
{ 
  "environment" : "1", 
  "memory_oversubscription" : 1,
  "cpu_oversubscription" : 1 
}
```

If you really want the result under the _id field for some reasons, a $project whould be much better :

```
db.environments.aggregate([
  {$match:{"customer" : "CustomerName"}},
  {$project: 
    {_id : 
      {"environment" : "$environment",
       "memory_oversubscription" : "$memory_oversubscription", 
       "cpu_oversubscription" : "$cpu_oversubscription"}
    }
  }
]);
```

Result :

```
{ "_id" : { "environment" : "1", 
            "memory_oversubscription" : 1, 
            "cpu_oversubscription" : 1 } 
}
```

Doesn't make sense to me, but maybe it does for you :-).